# Is there any way to view JavaScript function as object in the Crome console?

Tags: javascript

When I run the code:

```
function F35() { return this; }
F35.Speed = 2600;
console.log('Here is the function:', F35);
console.log('Here is the property:', F35.Speed);
```

The output is like this:

```
 Here is the function: ƒ F35() { return this; }
 Here is the property: 2600
```

There is no arrow sign near the function that allows me to open its properties. While if I log an object, this is possible. Can I do the same with function? Every function has additional properties, like the prototype and maybe others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `.dir()` you could also place the function in brackets like this:

```
console.log({F35})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? What these curly braces mean here?

Comment: @Web-Intern it is an object literal created using [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). It is equivalent to `{ "F35": F35 }`

Answer (score 4):

You can view extended information about your function using `console.dir` instead of `console.log`:

```
console.dir(F35);
```

Specifically:

> The `Console` method `dir()` displays an interactive list of the
>   properties of the specified JavaScript object

The information about this is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Chrome guys could do this right in the log function just to simplify everything.

Comment: Just want to add: `console.dir('Here is the function:', F35);` will not work as you think, only `console.dir(F35);` will show the function properties, it's only the first argument

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using console.dir

```
console.dir(F35);
```